# How to interpret the status of an Azure VM's instanceView?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

It's possible to get information [about a VM's "instance view"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163682.aspx). This is how we'd figure out if a VM is stopped, running, etc. However, the data that Azure returns is a bit cryptic and entirely undocumented (the official documentation says absolutely nothing at all about this).

The `statuses` array seems to be the one of most usefulness. I've managed to piece together some patterns about its values. For example, it usually contains two objects, one stating the `ProvisioningState` and the other being the `PowerState`. I don't understand exactly what `ProvisioningState` means (**so what exactly is the `ProvisioningState`?**).

I notice that a combination of `ProvisioningState/succeeded` and some other status seems to imply "this is the final status" (running, stopped, generalized, etc). If it's `ProvisioningState/updating`, then it's a lot weirder. I've seen it have no secondary state, I've seen it be running at this time (and the site seems accessible on that VM).

So that brings me to my second question: **what does it mean for `ProvisioningState` to be `updating` or `creating`, yet the `PowerState` is running and the VM seems entirely functional?**

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is there better documentation on Azure's REST APIs besides the MSDN? I feel like I'm going crazy here because the MSDN usually has excellent documentation, but Azure's documentation is so horribly, horribly bad (vast amounts of outdated and missing information).

Comment: To make things even more confusing, I just saw `ProvisioningState/failed/OSProvisioningTimedOut` (which the Azure portal called simply "failed"), yet the VM seems to be working and accessible.

Comment: Mike - please edit your question rather than putting additional information/questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few variations. There are probably much more, but these might help someone:

The `PowerState/` code, has the following values for the `displayStatus`: `VM starting`, `VM running`, `VM deallocating`, `VM deallocated`

If a VM is being deleted the, `PowerState/` code disappears and you only have the `ProvisioningState/` code with the value `Deleting` for the `displayStatus`.